# Olevia model 237-T11 TV won't turn on

Tags: repair

So my Olevia model 237-T11 tv stopped working the other day. Now mind you, I tried everything from unplugging, waiting 30 minutes, replugging it into the outlet, using different power outlets, etc. Also keep in mind that I have no knowledge in this field, but I'd like to at least crack it open before I'm going to throw it away (Not willing to spend $200-$300 on repairs either).

The TV usually would have a blue led light turned on when in standby mode, but even the light won't turn on when I plug in the TV. The TV won't even show a display when I try to turn it on.

Did some researching online and found out the capacitors on the power supply board go bad easily. I was willing to buy new capacitors and solder them on. So I decided to open it up and take a look. Didn't find any capacitors with bulging heads. I was wondering if its a problem with a fuse or anything else?

Your input will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here's a link to the album of pics of the circuit board.

https://plus.google.com/photos/104181613206889253838/albums/5817169079436369889?authkey=CLGVkr7N7rbkvQE

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Too little information for a qualified response. In general, if no fuses are visible and blown, electolytic capacitor replacement is a good starting point once one opens up any electronics more than a couple of years old for repair. Troubleshooting continues from there.

Comment: Have you used *olfactory diagnostics* yet? (sniff the board to check if anything smells burnt)

Comment: Nothing smells burnt. I was planning on getting new caps, but I'm not completely sure if that will fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no electronics knowledge, then either get it repaired of buy the replacement power board (and preferably get someone with some experience to fit it for you) If it's simply not powering up then it's likely to be a power supply issue - caps can be bad without bulging or leaking (often they will eventually, but increased ESR or similar can cause problems before anything is clearly visible.

If it was a low voltage piece of equipment, I'd say go for it, but messing around with mains voltage is potentially (pardon the pun) rather lethal.

If you are determined to go ahead anyway, we'd need a lot more info and detailed close up pictures, plus info on any test equipment you have available.

Comment: I posted a link of the pics, so I hope that will help. A lot of people had the same problem and fixed it by soldering new caps onto the board. I was just wondering what other factors play a role when I'm trying to get the TV to turn on. I'm not really trying to mess with the voltage either.

Comment: Okay, thanks - no time to look in detail now (I added some of the images into your question), but I will when I get a few mins spare. I'm sure others will give some good suggestions/answers as well. Do you have a multimeter, LCR meter or ESR meter?

Comment: Ok thank you. And sadly no, I have minimal equipment.

Comment: Not having a multimeter doesn't really qualify as minimal ... more like "no" equipment. There's little point to try and troubleshoot solely visually.

Answer (score 1):

> Also keep in mind that I have no knowledge in this field

Playing around with anything mains-powered without some basic electronics knowledge is dangerous. Incidental contact with mains-powered circuits can be lethal.

When it comes to mains-powered gadgets, a tube TV is even *more* dangerous:

- the voltage driving the tube itself is in the tens of thousands of volts
- the tube can remain charged for days or weeks after power is lost

> I was wondering if its a problem with a fuse or anything else?

"Anything else" is most likely where the problem is, and no, I'm not deliberately trying to be pedantic.

Fuse blows aren't problems *per se*. Fuses blow to prevent hazardous conditions (like a failed TV) from burning down your house. If the fuse did blow, it did so when heavy current flowed, and isolated the circuit from the mains to prevent the failure from creating a safety hazard - that's what fuses do.

Even if you do get some basic equipment (like a multimeter) you really shouldn't consider trying to fix a TV without a service manual or a schematic. Unless you're experienced, you may make an inappropriate or inadvertent component substitution and risk doing some real damage to yourself and your property.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to electrocute yourself while doing the following. Also, in the first picture you posted, there is a large connector that is disconnected in the bottom left of the picture.

The first thing you should try to do is make sure the tv is plugged in and there is no blown fuse or kill switch (some TV's have a switch on the bottom that completely cuts off power, like the power supply on a PC has.) Then take a blow dryer and slowly heat up sections while continually pressing the power button (give it about 10 seconds between presses.)

Hopefully the unit will turn on after ~ 10mins, but it could take more. I have had several brand new TV's that will only turn on intermittently. The blow dryer trick worked on all of them, although sometimes it takes a while. This will also help you identify where the problem component is. Although I had one TV that as far as I can tell it will only turn on once the screen is warm.

If this doesn't work, you can try to do the opposite, and use a instant freeze spray on components while trying to turn it on. Just be careful not to let any components get wet and short.